# how to arrange a list of df base on another file

Tags: r

If I have a list of df `lst`, and I would lkie to rearrange each df as follow (Order is stored as another df `OL`) , what should I do?

[image]

I tried to do using map and it doesn't work. I think I am looping wrong. Any suggestion?

```
lst[OL$Data] <-map(lst[OL$Data] , ~ .x %>% 
          arrange(paste(OL$Order)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are doing this on corresponding columns of 'OL' i.e. the `lst` names are stored in 'Data' and we want to order only the corresponding column stored in 'Order', use `map2` to loop over 'lst' element based on the names in 'Data' and the 'Order' column, then `arrange` with `across`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst[OL$Data] <- map2(lst[OL$Data], OL$Order, ~ .x %>% 
                          arrange(across(all_of(.y))))
```

Comment: @Stataq based on the image you showed, I assume `OL$Order` as the column names of the list elements

Comment: @Stataq when you do `lst[OL$Data]` it is only selecting those elements in 'lst' that match its name based on the Data column.  You would need to assign back i..e `lst[OL$Data] <-`

Comment: @Stataq please show a small reproducible example with expected output as this is getting confusing